# Java robot cannot control the whole keyboard

Tags: java, keyboard, automation

I tried to make a sort of keyboard controller class but the java robot seems to be unable to conrol the whole keyboard.

I tried

```
robot.keyPress(i);
Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
robot.keyRelease(i);
```

from 0 to 255 and this key is never pressed (this key is present on all azerty keyboard).

[image]

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Ps : you don't need to press CTRL or ALT in order to use this key, it produce this : "²"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try creating a new window, and have it capture and print out the key codes for the keys pressed. Then run it and press the key in question. it should then print the `KeyCode` for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame();
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getExtendedKeyCode());
        }            
    });
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

doing this with a virtual keyboard gave me **16777394**

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED for all the 'KeyCode' values

Comment: @vandale in every keyboard this keys will have this keyCode...?

Comment: @crAlexander it depends what you mean by this key: they at that physical location's value will vary based on the layout. However, the key with that value should have a consistent keycode regardless of location (numpad keys notwithstanding)

Comment: @vandale for example if i have the code(134 ) and i say if(Keycode==134) it will find the VK_DEAD_ABOVEDOT if exists or this keycode could come from another button?

Comment: @crAlexander it could come from any button the user wants to be treated as VK_DEAD_ABOVEDOT. The user could set every key on the keyboard as 'a' if they wanted to. A mouse could even be creating the keyboard event . So yes, assume the key exists, but make no assumptions about its physical location on the keyboard