# Detect KeyBoard Special Keys with java?

Tags: java, keylistener

I want to know how i can detect keyboard special keys like these:

[image]

I know how to use KeyListeners but i can't find these keys there. Is it possible with pure java, or do I need external libraries?

I want to use this keys like the normal keys(VK_1,VK_2,..)

**One example:**

The most games(rpg,online adventure etc...) automatically search and find the special keys from keyboard and mouse[So i can use them if exist] [How i can achieve this at least for one key].

Comment: F9, F10, F11, F12 are easy. The other four above are vendor specific to your keyboard, so, unless your keyboard maker has opened an API to access those keys you probably won't be able to read them.

Comment: You could try printing the keycodes in the listener to see what happens if you press these keys and then use the printed codes in your programm. This will very very likely only work as expected with the specific keyboard, but at least it will work with this specific keyboard.

Comment: @ElGavilian thanks for reply! Hm when i play a game for example(those rpg) how they detect the special keys(from keyboard and mouse...)?There is not a library there to find were the special keys are or if they exist?

Comment: @Soana thanks for reply! Hm when i play a game for example(those rpg) how they detect the special keys(from keyboard and mouse...)?There is not a library there to find were the special keys are or if they exist?

Comment: code for @Soana 's suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802772/java-robot-cannot-control-the-whole-keyboard/18802888#18802888